# Gitlab ssh runner not working, but no errors, only timeout, why?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

try configure ssh runner, runner have status active, but if i try run pipeline - job freeze and get timeout.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.10.0 (456e3482)
  on test-nomad2 BPzKEMnh, system ID: s_3bb23e681869
Preparing the "ssh" executor
Using SSH executor...
ERROR: Preparation failed: ssh command Connect() error: ssh Dial() error: dial tcp myip:21223: connect: connection timed out
```

My runner is a qemu VM in Proxmox with ssh port 21223.
My runner config:

```
 `[[runners]]
  name = "test-nomad2"
  url = "https://my.gitlab.url/"
  id = 35
  token = "token"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-03-22T05:17:14Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "ssh"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.ssh]
    user = "gitlab"
    host = "server.dns.name"
    port = "21223"
    identity_file = "/home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ed25519"`
```

No any info in gitlab runner log, except timeout. i don't know what i can do

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass arguments to the SSH command? On Linux the SSH version of the program, there are three-levels of logging verbosity. Pass the argument '-v' and you can add more like '-vv' and '-vvv'. Hope that helps.